# Excel/VBA Pivoting a column and listing all unique values under column regardless of of number in other columns

Tags: excel, vba, validation, pivot

I'm having an Issue in Excel where I have to convert an unpivoted column (States) whilst keeping the next column (Vendors) linked, but only keeping unique values. This so I can apply a data validated drop-down list to each state with a list of vendors to select as part of a sensitivity analysis.

My Current Data looks like this:

| State | Vendor |
| --- | --- |
| NY | Netflix |
| NY | Netflix |
| CA | Binge |
| CA | Binge |
| CA | Netflix |
| NY | Binge |
| MA | Hulu |
| MA | Netflix |
| MA | Binge |

I'm Trying to make my data look like this, however it will involve almost 70 different state values, and thousands of duplicate Vendor values.

| NY | CA | MA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Netflix | Netflix | Hulu |
| Binge | Binge | Netflix |
|  |  | Binge |

Is it possible to achieve something like this through VBA? Due to the predicted size of the dataset I doubt there is any other feasible method to achieve except for automation of some kind.

Any help or directions to similar problems that have been answered would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Pivot Column Using a Dictionary of Dictionaries

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PivotColumn()
    Const ProcName As String = "PivotColumn"
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' cover unexpected errors

    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sPivotColumnFirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    Const sValuesWorksheetColumnIndex As Variant = "B" ' or 2
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Write the source column values to arrays.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    Dim sprg As Range
    Dim srCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range(sPivotColumnFirstCellAddress)
        Dim splCell As Range
        Set splCell = .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If splCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No data in pivot column range.", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        srCount = splCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set sprg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With
    
    Dim svrg As Range
    Set svrg = sprg.EntireRow.Columns(sValuesWorksheetColumnIndex)
    
    Dim spData As Variant
    Dim svData As Variant
    
    If srCount = 1 Then ' one row
        ReDim spData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): spData(1, 1) = sprg.Value
        ReDim svData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): svData(1, 1) = svrg.Value
    Else ' multiple rows
        spData = sprg.Value
        svData = svrg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Write the unique source column values from the arrays
    ' to a dictionary of dictionaries.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim pKey As Variant
    Dim vKey As Variant
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim drCount As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        pKey = spData(sr, 1)
        If Not IsError(pKey) Then ' exclude error values
            If Len(pKey) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                vKey = svData(sr, 1)
                If Not IsError(vKey) Then ' exclude error values
                    If Len(vKey) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                        If Not dict.Exists(pKey) Then
                            Set dict(pKey) _
                                = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                        End If
                        dict(pKey)(vKey) = Empty
                        If dict(pKey).Count > drCount Then
                            drCount = dict(pKey).Count
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next sr
    
    If drCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No valid data found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Write the unique values from the dictionary to an array.
    
    Erase spData
    Erase svData
    
    drCount = drCount + 1  ' rows (include headers)
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = dict.Count ' columns
    
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
    
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim dc As Long
    
    For Each pKey In dict.Keys
        dc = dc + 1
        dData(1, dc) = pKey
        dr = 1
        For Each vKey In dict(pKey).Keys
            dr = dr + 1
            dData(dr, dc) = vKey
            'Debug.Print pKey, vKey
        Next vKey
    Next pKey
    
    ' Write the values from the array to the destination worksheet.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    
    With dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress).Resize(, dcCount)
        ' Clear previous data below and to the right of the first cell
        ' (cells above and to the left stay intact).
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, dws.Columns.Count - .Column + 1) _
            .Clear
        ' Write.
        .Resize(drCount).Value = dData
        ' Format.
        .Font.Bold = True ' headers
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit ' columns
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Column pivoted.", vbInformation

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit

End Sub
```